# Why do I get different EOL for different files?

Tags: windows-xp, notepad++, carriage-return, linefeed

What can cause Notepad++ to make new lines as `CRLF` in one file and only `LF` in the other?

Both files were created at the same folder from the same OS and no modifications to Notepad++ preferences were made, AFAIK... Is there any option in Notepad++ that changes how new lines are defined?

Comment: Why the closing votes? Is it not a fair question? Programmers don't use Notepad++? Wrong place to post? If it's the latest I'll delete it myself, although I think it is programming related...

Comment: 1) Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889163/eol-in-notepad-and-notepad which also has a comment that such question belongs to superuser: this is a question about a software, even if it is a programming tool, not a question about programming.  
2) View EOL chars with the ¶ button in the toolbar, change them with Format > Convert to Xxx format, set the default in Preferences > New Document > Format. Found that with a quick exploration of this editor which I have but don't use regularly...

Comment: Mmm, looking at the FAQ again, I see that questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are OK. Perhaps it was about tools like sed or bison, but I suppose text editors can fit there too, even if your question is a bit borderline... (was not about editing source code, for example).

Comment: Thank you PhiLho. There's no way to improve or make better questions if no one cares to explain what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Edit->EOL Conversion` -- change setting to `Windows Format` or `Unix Format` or `Old Mac Format` (depending on your prefernces)